# Does every prime ideal of a ring contain a minimal prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $\mathfrak p \subset R$ a prime ideal. I think that it is easy to show that $\mathfrak p$ contains a minimal prime ideal of $R$, by the following argument: pass to the localization $\varphi : R \to R_\mathfrak p$, fetch a minimal prime $\mathfrak q \subset R_\mathfrak p$ and contract it back to $R$ to get a minimal prime $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak q) \subset \mathfrak p$. However, the commutative algebra wiki [suggests](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring_has_finitely_many_minimal_primes_and_every_prime_contains_a_minimal_prime) that only in a Noetherian ring do prime ideals always contain a minimal prime.

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning, and, if so, what is it?

Comment: Why can you "fetch a minimal prime $\mathfrak{q} \subset R_\mathfrak{p}$"? Localization preserves ideals contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: Because $R_\mathfrak p$ is a local ring, hence not the zero ring, hence it contains minimal prime ideals with respect to inclusion.

Comment: Wow, I must be tired tonight. Anyway, yes, of course. [Stacks Lemma 10.16.2(4)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00E0) says it explicitly.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use localizations.

**Hint:** The intersection of any decreasing chain of prime ideals is a prime ideal. Hence by Zorn's lemma every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal.

Comment: It is really the same argument in disguise, right?

Comment: I am not sure it is the same.