# Nilradical is the intersection of the minimal prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove that the Nilradical of a ring $A$ is the intersection of the minimal prime ideals. The one inclusion is obvious but I cannot do the other. I am just taking an $x$ which belongs to the intersection of all minimal prime ideals and I am trying to prove that it belongs to the intersection of all primes.

I know that a prime ideal $p$ is minimal if there is no prime between the $(0)$ and $p$. But how can I relate an arbitrary prime ideal with the minimal ones? Does it hold that every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal over the $(0)$ ideal?

Comment: Every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal, so the intersection of all prime ideals is the same as the intersection of all minimal prime ideals.

Comment: Why every prime ideal contains a minimal prime?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833011/does-every-prime-ideal-of-a-ring-contain-a-minimal-prime), or  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703673/existence-of-minimal-prime-ideal-contained-in-given-prime-ideal-and-containing-a/2493455).